# can I use the cluster module to make a function handler happen in a different process?

Tags: node.js, multicore

I'm building out a "manager" process with a set of workers. I'd like to put the workers into separate processes using the `cluster` ([link](http://nodejs.org/api/cluster.html#cluster_cluster)) module. Since the worker's message processing may be fairly resource intensive it makes sense to push it to a different core.

Here's the pseudo code for the manager:

```
  for i in worker_count
    create a new process (fork = cluster.fork())       
    create a worker and pass in the process (fork) to its constructor 
    in the worker
      when the worker gets a "work" chunk 
         it should be processed on a core that is not the same as the manager
```

I can't find much information on cluster that isn't just `http.createServer` etc. I can do this a different way but I'm wondering if there's a way to grab the "context" of the cluster and put a function inside that context.

Answer (score 1):

When you fork the cluster, it duplicates the current process entirely. There is one 'master' worker and the rest are all created as child processes. One way to pass work to the child workers is to send messages:

```
if (cluster.isMaster) {
    // Spawn all your child workers here
    var worker = cluster.fork();

    // You could send a message to the worker from here if you wanted
    worker.send('some message');

    // You could loop through all the workers and send messages to them
    for (var id in cluster.workers) {
        cluster.workers[id].send('some message');
    }

} else {

    // This is where your child workers will branch into as they are not the master process
    process.on('message', function (msg) {
        if (msg === "some message") {
            doSomeStuff();
        }
    });
}
```